# Nothing happens when I attempt to generate account-linking code in Rock Band 3

Tags: rock-band-3

I'm trying to obtain the "Well connected" goal, which involves entering the account-linking code on the Rock Band website.

The problem is, when I click "Get account-linking code", it just sits on "Fetching account linking code" forever.  Is there something magical I need to do to get this to work?  Or am I just so long after the crowd that they've shut down the server?  (They still have the link on the webpage, so that seems unlikely...)

If relevant, it's the Wii version and I'm in Australia...

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer possible to achieve this goal / achievement / trophy, due to changes in the layout and functionality of RockBand.com. Here's what Harmonix has to say about it:

> We’re sorry, but account linking is no longer available for Rock Band 3 on RockBand.com. The layout and functionality of RockBand.com has changed considerably in the years since the release of Rock Band 3, and as a result account linking is no longer functional. If you have not linked your account previously, you will not be able to complete the “Well Connected” Career Goal or the “Well Connected” achievement / trophy in Rock Band 3.

[Source](http://harmonixmusic.parature.com/link/portal/16080/16097/Article/60/My-webcode-account-linking-code-isn-t-working-Can-I-have-a-new-one).